# How to set Smooth Scroll in Sticky Navbar?

Tags: html, css, scroll, sticky

i have a sticky menu has children. like this template :

```
<ul id="sticky">
 <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
 <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
 <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

and div tags on page is :

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

so i want click on item and scroll to item div but sticky nav is problem.

after scroll on item , selected item displayed under sticky navbar.

how i can set offset to (scroll-behavior: smooth) or any way to fix this prob?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before with my website but fear not a bit of javascript can fix this issue try putting this in your js script file or javascript inside the html file

```js
$(".smooth-scroll").click(function(e) {
        let currentItem = e.target.text;
        console.log(currentItem);
        $("html, body").animate(
          {
            scrollTop:
              $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top -
              (currentItem == "Skills" ? 100 : 100)
          },
          "fast"
        );
        return false;
      });
```

```html
<ul id="sticky">
 <li><a class="smooth-scroll" href="#one">One</a></li>
 <li><a class="smooth-scroll" href="#two">Two</a></li>
 <li><a class="smooth-scroll" href="#three">Three</a></li>
</ul>


<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
```